# How do I Write and Retrieve Multiple Records Using inFile?

Tags: c++, file-io, save

I have a homework assignment were I have to store parking ticket information and retrieve the data.  So I thought it would be easier to store the information into a txt file like so:

```
void v_input(string ticket, string f_name, string l_name, string address, 
string city, string plate, string vin, string violation, string v_code, 
double amount, double l_fee, string make, string model, bool paid, int date, 
int time, int payby, int officer_no) 

{

ofstream inFile;
inFile.open("tickets.txt");
if (inFile.is_open()) {

inFile << ticket << "\n" << f_name << "\n" << l_name << "\n" << address << "\n" << city << "\n" << plate << "\n"
<< vin << "\n" << violation << "\n" << v_code << "\n" << amount << "\n" << l_fee << "\n" << make << "\n" << model
<< "\n" << paid << "\n" << date << "\n" << time << "\n" << payby << "\n" << officer_no << "\n" << endl;

}

    //Check for Error

if (inFile.fail()) {

cout << "tickets.txt is Corrupted" << endl;
exit(1);

}
```

This works good, except that it seems to overwrite the file.  What I really want is it to add a separate record each time (no overwrite) that the program is ran.

Also I need to craft a way to search each individual record.  This is what I have thus far:

```
void plate_search() {

string search;
string line;

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("tickets.txt");

if (!inFile) {
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

cout << "Please enter a plate Number to search : " << endl;
cin >> search;

size_t pos;
while (inFile.good())
{
    getline(inFile, line); // get line from file
    pos = line.find(search); // search
    if (pos != string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not 
found
    {
        cout << "Found!";
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see it's just a generic search and it will pull everything in the search parameters.

What I need to do is to have it recognize each entry as an individual record and pull those specific tickets.  I can do this by adding a specific token to denote an end of one record (i.e. each record should end in ####) but I'm not sure how to implement it?

Q1: How would I be able to have inFile write separate records into the txt file instead of overwriting them?

Q2: How would I be able to narrow my search query to a separate record?

Comment: Handy reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode . You want `app` to append.

Comment: Organize your data more intelligently. Instead of a spray of many related variables, build all of the variables into a structure. Then write functions that read and write the structure. When you read, read into the structure, then check if the appropriate member matches the search key eg, `if (violationrecord.plate == searchplate) { dosomething(); }`

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, I just talked to my teacher, and she also said to research append.  Also thanks for the structure tip.